# How to arrange files within Xcode application groups?

Tags: xcode

In X code, I have added 3 groups named

```
* Classes
* COCOS2d
* Images
```

Under images, I have added 40 files. But all images under IMAGEs group aren't sorted by name.

I want to sort them, but I didn't found any option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the images in the group tree under your images group, then choose Edit > Sort > By Name from the menu.

Comment: Superb. Superb. In super user till Now, No body answered.

Comment: what about XCode4 - There is no such option in edit menu in XCode4. :(

Comment: Yeah I don't see anything like it either. Might not be possible. :(