# XCode4 - Arranging-sorting Groups

Tags: ios, sorting, ios4, xcode4, grouping

This is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522863) for sorting groups within Project tree.
It works fine for XCode different versions, but It doesn't works for XCode4.

Here, I am asking for sorting groups,files,frameworks within project-tree.
 Here is the snapshot of unsorted files within my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple & straight in new Xcode4.2

1. Select your files/Folders/Groups
2. Go to Edit Menu => Sort => By Name/Type

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange everything within the project navigator of XCode 4 just by dragging & dropping. There is no way (currently) to sort items in the project navigator. File a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com), that's the only way Apple will know people want a feature.

Comment: manual arrangement ! That is not a good option if there are 15 to 20 groups :(

Comment: If you arrange as part of the process of adding files, it really isn't that bad. I have a couple projects with more than 200 source files, I've been creating groups and adding new files directly to those groups as I code. What kind of automatic organization are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Just try to have a quick look over "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522863". It is the same question & It has proper solution for it in XCode3 & not in XCode4.

Comment: Updated answer now that I realize what you're looking for. It isn't possible currently, I asked for the same thing while at WWDC, the XCode team told me to file bug reports.

Comment: In latest XCode 4.2 its possible now. Check my answer below.